# What’s the best way to bulk database inserts from c#?

Tags: c#, sql-server

How do I/what’s the best way to do bulk database inserts?

In C#, I am iterating over a collection and calling an insert stored procedure for each item in the collection.

How do I send all the data in one database call?

E.g. say I have a person list (`List<Person>`) containing 10 items. I am currently calling the InsertPerson stored proc 10 times. I would like to reduce this to 1 call.

I am using MS SQL Server 2005.

Comment: Definitely check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/629455/how-should-i-optimize-multiple-calls-in-my-net-code-to-a-trivial-stored-procedur). The topvoted answer (no, it's not mine:p) presents a very elegant solution to this exact problem.

Comment: thanks for asking this question

Answer (score 29):

CsharperGuyInLondon, here's a simple example of SqlBulkCopy code:

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;

DataTable table = new DataTable("States");
// construct DataTable
table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("id_state", typeof(int))); 
table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("state_name", typeof(string)));

// note: if "id_state" is defined as an identity column in your DB,
// row values for that column will be ignored during the bulk copy
table.Rows.Add("1", "Atlanta");
table.Rows.Add("2", "Chicago");
table.Rows.Add("3", "Springfield");

using(SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connectionString))
{
  bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 600; // in seconds
  bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "state";
  bulkCopy.WriteToServer(table);
}
```

Comment: I appreciate this sample code. Saved me lots of time. iteratively inserting 17k (32 columns per row) records takes about 200ish seconds under my network settings. Using this method takes less than 10 seconds.

Comment: Some thoughts You no longer need to create a DataColoumn Object you can pass the column name and type directly into the Add Function now Add("id_state", typeof(int)); Also the table layout needs to match that of the table in sql. Column order aswell

Answer (score 25):

Well, 10 items isn't what I call bulk, but for larger sets, `SqlBulkCopy` is your friend. All you need to do is feed it either a `DataTable` or an `IDataReader` (my preferred option, 'cos I like streaming APIs). I did something similar [here](http://groups.google.co.uk/group/microsoft.public.dotnet.languages.csharp/msg/91c7a20056ffe8e1) (you can ignore the xml side - just subclass the SimpleDataReader).

Comment: Marc: do you know what's under the hood of SqlBulkCopy?

Comment: +1 for "streaming APIS".  @Jason, my guess is SqlBulkCopy wraps the BULK insert statement: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187042.aspx

Comment: Sorry - was AFK - it is essentially the same API as "bcp" etc use - but directly via a TDS stream (it doesn't wrap an exe, or similar).

Answer (score 7):

The .NET [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) class works quite well.

Answer (score 3):

Re the solution for SqlBulkCopy, I created a class than takes `Datatable` or a `List<T>` and a Buffer size (`CommitBatchSize`). It will convert the list to a data table using an extension (in the second class).

It works very fast. On my PC, I am able to insert more than 10 million complicated records in less than 10 seconds.

Here is the class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DAL
{

public class BulkUploadToSql<T>
{
    public IList<T> InternalStore { get; set; }
    public string TableName { get; set; }
    public int CommitBatchSize { get; set; }=1000;
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }

    public void Commit()
    {
        if (InternalStore.Count>0)
        {
            DataTable dt;
            int numberOfPages = (InternalStore.Count / CommitBatchSize)  + (InternalStore.Count % CommitBatchSize == 0 ? 0 : 1);
            for (int pageIndex = 0; pageIndex < numberOfPages; pageIndex++)
                {
                    dt= InternalStore.Skip(pageIndex * CommitBatchSize).Take(CommitBatchSize).ToDataTable();
                BulkInsert(dt);
                }
        } 
    }

    public void BulkInsert(DataTable dt)
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            // make sure to enable triggers
            // more on triggers in next post
            SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy =
                new SqlBulkCopy
                (
                connection,
                SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock |
                SqlBulkCopyOptions.FireTriggers |
                SqlBulkCopyOptions.UseInternalTransaction,
                null
                );

            // set the destination table name
            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = TableName;
            connection.Open();

            // write the data in the "dataTable"
            bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);
            connection.Close();
        }
        // reset
        //this.dataTable.Clear();
    }

}

public static class BulkUploadToSqlHelper
{
    public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> data)
    {
        PropertyDescriptorCollection properties =
            TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
            table.Columns.Add(prop.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) ?? prop.PropertyType);
        foreach (T item in data)
        {
            DataRow row = table.NewRow();
            foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
                row[prop.Name] = prop.GetValue(item) ?? DBNull.Value;
            table.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        return table;
    }
}
```

}

Here is an example when I want to insert a List of my custom object `List<PuckDetection>` (`ListDetections`):

```
var objBulk = new BulkUploadToSql<PuckDetection>()
{
        InternalStore = ListDetections,
        TableName= "PuckDetections",
        CommitBatchSize=1000,
        ConnectionString="ENTER YOU CONNECTION STRING"
};
objBulk.Commit();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can build a BLOB (image) and send it as a parameter to a stored procedure. Inside the stored procedure, you can fetch all the items using substring().

Answer (score 2):

Here's a good example of `SqlBulkCopy` in action:

http://blogs.msdn.com/nikhilsi/archive/2008/06/11/bulk-insert-into-sql-from-c-app.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I construct the list as an xml string and pass it to the stored proc. In SQL 2005, it has enhanced xml functionalities to parse the xml and do a bulk insert.

check this post:
[Passing lists to SQL Server 2005 with XML Parameters](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2007/02/16/passing-lists-to-sql-server-2005-with-xml-parameters.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Dump your data to a pipe delimited (or something else if your data has pipes in it) text file and use [Bulk Insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx).

Comment: The method needs to be programatic and fast - no disk i/o. Thank you.

Comment: You could do it using MemoryStream to avoid File I/O, but you're probably just doing a boilerplate implementation SQLBulkCopy. See my comment to @Mark Gavell's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could update with an Xml document, Sql 2005 works very well with them.  One node per row, but just one parameter for Xml.

Answer (score 1):

Create a XML document that contains all the items to be inserted.  Then inside of a stored procedure, use the TSQL xml support ([OPENXML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186918.aspx)) to read all the data from the XML document and insert it into your tables with hopefully one insert statement for each table.

However if you are only inserting data into a single table and don’t need any database side logic, why not use [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx)?

Comment: You don't need to use OPENXML with SQL 2005, just use the built in XML data type.

Comment: @Adam, OPENXML is still usefull if you are just using the XML as a way to transport rows.  However the SQL 2005 XML data types are very useful if you wish to store the XML in te database.