# Batch operations using ADO.NET

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, .net-4.6.1

I'm trying to make batch insert using ADO.NET. So far I found, that using `SqlDataAdapter` might be a way to do it.

I've created database with 1 table and 3 columns and stored procedure which will insert rows into this table.

Table `PropertyTable`:

```
Name: VARCHAR(10)
Number: INT
IsActive: BIT
```

Stored procedure `InsertPropertyTable`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertPropertyTable
    @Par1 VARCHAR(10),
    @Par2 INT,
    @Par3 BIT
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.PropertyTable
    VALUES (@Par1, @Par2, @Par3)
END
GO
```

C# code:

```cs
namespace InsertManyTest.Console
{
    using System;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var connString = "Server=.;Database=Test;Trusted_Connection=True;";
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connString))
            {
                var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("", connection);

                var dataTable = new DataTable();
                dataTable.Columns.AddRange(new[]
                {
                    new DataColumn("Par1", typeof(string)),
                    new DataColumn("Par2", typeof(int)),
                    new DataColumn("Par3", typeof(bool))
                });

                adapter.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("InsertPropertyTable", connection);
                adapter.InsertCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                adapter.InsertCommand.UpdatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.None;

                adapter.DeleteCommand = new SqlCommand();
                adapter.DeleteCommand.UpdatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.None;
                adapter.UpdateCommand = new SqlCommand();
                adapter.UpdateCommand.UpdatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.None;
                adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand();
                adapter.SelectCommand.UpdatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.None;

                adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Par1", SqlDbType.VarChar,10, "Par1");
                adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Par2", SqlDbType.Int, 1, "Par2");
                adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Par3", SqlDbType.Bit, 1, "Par3");

                CreateRow(dataTable);
                CreateRow(dataTable);
                CreateRow(dataTable);
                CreateRow(dataTable);

                adapter.UpdateBatchSize = 2;
                adapter.Update(dataTable);
            }
        }

        private static void CreateRow(DataTable dataTable)
        {
            var row = dataTable.NewRow();
            FillRow(row);
            dataTable.Rows.Add(row);
        }

        private static void FillRow(DataRow row)
        {
            row["Par1"] = "Asd";
            row["Par2"] = 1;
            row["Par3"] = true;
        }
    }
}
```

When `UpdateBatchSize` is set to the default value (`1`), it's working but makes round trip for each insert. I would like to avoid that so I've set `UpdateBatchSize` to some bigger value, but then I get some weird exception:

> System.ArgumentException: 'Specified parameter name 'Parameter1' is not valid.'

from `adaper.Update(...);`

I've expected that this update would generate something like:

```
sp_exec InsertPropertyTable 'Asd', 1;
sp_exec InsertPropertyTable 'Asd', 1;
sp_exec InsertPropertyTable 'Asd', 1;
sp_exec InsertPropertyTable 'Asd', 1;
```

which would be executed in single round trip to database

---

Update:
I've found this issue on stack overflow and author is making similar things to me. In his case it's working and he makes comparisons with other ways to bulk insert

[Bulk insert using SP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870022/bulk-inserting-best-way-to-about-it-helping-me-understand-fully-what-i-found)

[Blog post from 2008](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25457/Multiple-Ways-to-do-Multiple-Inserts)

---

Update:

I'm a dummy dumb dumb. I was testing this in .net core 2.2 and not on .net 4.6.1.
It's not working on .net core 2.2 but it kinda works on .net 4.6.1.

I'm not seeing result I've expected as there are several rows in sql server profiler. Each row contains single `exec ...`.

Comment: Are you sure there should `@` in front of the parameter names when indexing into the `DataRow`?

Comment: @PalleDue works with `UpdateBatchSize=1` and stops working whenever I change that.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you might make use of Table-Valued parameters.

Basically, you create new custom type on SQL Server side which reflects the data structure (one row) that you want to sent to the stored procedure. Then, you use that type to notify type of parameter that your stored procedure accepts. Once received in a stored procedure, you can query that table-valued parameter as any other table: for example, select everything from it and insert into your real table.

ref1: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017

ref2: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters

Comment: I know that `UserDefinedType` will work, but it's an extra effort to make it. Also if you want to insert one row you have to pretend you have a collection or make separate stored procedure