# Bulk Insert or Another way to load a lot of data at once using C# and SQL server?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, .net-3.5

I have an application where a user can upload files and associate the files with a project. The projects can be duplicated. Here is an example of an object:

```
Public class Project{
    Int ProjectId{get; set;}
    string ProjectName{get;set;}
    List<int> FileIds{get;set}
}
```

When I go to duplicate the project, say, what is the best way to associate the same files with a new project? I have two tables for projects and files. I have a relational table that has foreign keys to the project id and the file ids. When I create a new project id I want to bulk insert the file ids into the relational table. Is it just as good to iterate through the List and inert one at a time or is there a better way?

Comment: I did find this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/682015/whats-the-best-way-to-bulk-database-inserts-from-c

Comment: Can you clarify, are you copying the data from your projects table (and/or files table) back to the projects table, but modifying the ID's?

Comment: I am duplicating the data so it is treated like a whole new record. When the project gets duplicated a new project is created with a new ID.

Comment: SqlBulkCopy is definitely a good option, and would probably be sufficient for you as I imagine you're not copying more than a few hundred rows.  However, another approach which could be more performant would be to do this all on the database server.  You could use a SELECT INTO on your source records to a temp table, UPDATE the ID columns in your tempt able, then INSERT INTO...SELECT them back into the projects table.  That might be overkill for your needs, but it's a thought.

Comment: Since I already have the List<int> cna I pass that to the SQLBulkCopy? It seems I need to pass a datareader.

Comment: I guess I can convert the list to a datatable then do the insert. I'll try that!

Comment: HEre is alink to some cool code: http://lozanotek.com/blog/archive/2007/05/09/Converting_Custom_Collections_To_and_From_DataTable.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the project you're duplicating is already at the SQL Server by far the most efficient thing to do is to do the duplication at the SQL Server, just a simple:

`INSERT INTO Files (ProjectId,FileId) 
 SELECT 2 As ProjectId, FileId
 FROM Files WHERE ProjectId = 1`

Where the New Project is ProjectId=2 and the old one is ProjectId = 1

Answer (score 0):

Either use SqlBulkCopy or a Table-Valued Parameter to a stored procedure.

Comment: How can I apply that to a generic List<T>. Can I pass the list or convert it so I can use SQLBulkCopy?

Comment: If you're using SQL2008 I'd definitely look at User defined Table Types. Convert your List<T> to a datatable, add a SqlParamater of type SqlDbType.Structured and do your insert in the SP. It's a great tool to have in your skills arsenal

Comment: I wish I was using sql2008 ;) We are still on 2005