# Cassandra BULK INSERT using C#

Tags: c#, cassandra, datastax

I have application written in C# to load csv file to SqlServer using BULK INSERT command. Is there any similar command using C# Datastax  C# connector

During my search, found that it needs one by one insert but my csv can contain millions of rows.

Comment: You are looking for this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/682015/what-s-the-best-way-to-bulk-database-inserts-from-c-sharp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/682015/what-s-the-best-way-to-bulk-database-inserts-from-c-sharp)