# Getting Data from EventHub is delayed

Tags: azure, windows-services, azure-eventhub

I have an EventHub configured in Azure, also a consumer group for reading the data. It was working fine for some days. Suddenly, I see there is a delay in incoming data(around 3 days). I use Windows Service to consume data in my server. I have around 500 incoming messages per minute. Can anyone help me out to figure this out ?

Comment: How are you reading the data from the eventhub? Do you use an IEventProcessor instance?

Comment: @PeterBons Yes Peter, I am using IEventProcessor instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be that you are processing them items too slow. Therefore the work to be done grows and you will lag behind.

To get some insight in where you are in the event stream you can use code like this:

```
private void LogProgressRecord(PartitionContext context)
{
    if (namespaceManager == null)
        return;

    var currentSeqNo = context.Lease.SequenceNumber;
    var lastSeqNo = namespaceManager.GetEventHubPartition(context.EventHubPath, context.ConsumerGroupName, context.Lease.PartitionId).EndSequenceNumber;
    var delta = lastSeqNo - currentSeqNo;

    logWriter.Write(
            $"Last processed seqnr for partition {context.Lease.PartitionId}: {currentSeqNo} of {lastSeqNo} in consumergroup '{context.ConsumerGroupName}' (lag: {delta})",
            EventLevel.Informational);
}
```

the namespaceManager is build like this:

```
namespaceManager = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString("Endpoint=sb://xxx.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=yyy;SharedAccessKey=zzz");
```

I call this logging method in the `CloseAsync` method:

```
public Task CloseAsync(PartitionContext context, CloseReason reason)
{
    LogProgressRecord(context);

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

`logWriter` is just some logging class I have used to write info to blob storage.

It now outputs messages like

> Last processed seqnr for partition 3: 32780931 of 32823804 in consumergroup 'telemetry' (lag: 42873)

so when the lag is very high you could be processing events that have occurred a long time ago. In that case you need to scale up/out your processor.

If you notice a lag you should measure how long it takes to process a given number of item. You can then try to optimize performance and see whether it improves. We did it like:

```
public async Task ProcessEventsAsync(PartitionContext context, IEnumerable<EventData> events)
{
        try
        {
            stopwatch.Restart();

            // process items here

            stopwatch.Stop();

            await CheckPointAsync(context);

            logWriter.Write(
                $"Processed {events.Count()} events in {stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms using partition {context.Lease.PartitionId} in consumergroup {context.ConsumerGroupName}.",
                EventLevel.Informational);
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Peter for your valuable time.. I dont have any costly operation in the dataprocessor. I just insert the incoming record to a flat table using EF. I just checked the lag now and it is more than 100000 for each partition( have 4 partitions). Is it possible to run multiple instances of my windows service and make up the lag ?

Comment: Yes it is, but note that, depending on the database, it could be that EF / the DB just can't handle the load. 500 messages per second is not that much. You should measure the time of your operations. See updated answer.

Comment: Yeah may be. But I have a batch update of 25. May be 25 is a small number for it, I'll check. In between, is there any restriction for number of active listeners for a consumer group ? Because I also planned to make some more instances. In VS, it throwing fatal error if I try to run the already running consumer group for some minutes.

Comment: Maybe that for 25 records sql bulk copy is faster the using EF. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/682015/what-s-the-best-way-to-bulk-database-inserts-from-c

Comment: It depends on the number of partitions. One processing process per partition is optimal. Unfortunately you cannot increase number of partitions after you have created the event hub

Comment: So probably its better to create 4 instances for sake..correct ?

Comment: Yes, though I really recommend to measure and see what's best. If EF is the slowest factor you might not need 4 instances if you change to raw sql or sql bulk copy.

Comment: Ok, I'll try SqlBulkCopy first. If its not working will go to multiple instances. Thanks Peter.. :)